# How to access a local image using a local image url in a json file in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have problem in accessing the local image url in a json file. The images are stored in image directory. I have got some image addresses stored in a JSON array like this :

```
jsonResponse=
[ {"id": "1", "myImage": "./image/img1.png", "myText": "Anytext"},

…
]

const first = jsonResponse[0]
```

But when I try calling that using first.myImage in Image, it doesn't work;  I'm able to get everything else. So, I try calling it like:

```
source={require('{first.myImage}')} as well as source={require({first.myImage})}
```

But it says, invalid prop type. I am able to access all other elements. I have also updated the JSON as:

```
[ {"id": "1", "myImage": "require('./image/img1.png')", "myText": "Anytext"},

…
]
```

`source={first.myImage}` OR `source={{first.myImage}}`

but that gives the same error too. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

makesure you are accessing the image in the same directory where image resides or else navigate to the image with proper path

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are able to retrieve the filepath from the json file and that the path is correct. Based on that, try using:

```
jsonResponse = [{"id": "1", "myImage": "./image/img1.png", "myText": "Anytext"}, ...]
```

Then on your app create two const to hold your variables. The first one you'll use to save the path you retrieve from the json. The second will be the one you'll use as source of your Image component.

```
constructor() {
  const imagePath = first.myImage;
  const image = require(imagePath);
}

...

<Image 
   source={image}
   style={{ height: 30, width: 30, resizeMode: 'contain' }}
/>

...
```

Alternatively, you can also try importing the image this way:

```
import image from first.myImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
JSON File:

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Toyota Corolla XLI\\Hatchback Automatic",
    "details": "4 seater, diesel",
    "picture": "./static/images/XLI.jpg",
    "overcharge": "PKR 179 per excess km",
    "weekday": "PKR 190/hr",
    "weekend": "PKR 287/hr"
  },
  
  And then add inyour .js file like this:
  
{PostData.map((postDetail, index) => {
                return (
                  <Link href="details">
                    <Card className="carditem">
                      <Card.Body style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                        <Row>
                          <Col xs="12" sm="4">
                            <img
                              src={postDetail.picture}
                              class="d-block"
                              height="170"
                            />
```